# JQuery $.getJSON() Doesn't Work Right With Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

IT IS SOLVED - WAITING TO MARK (stackoverflow delay)

There's no error in firebug. I've done this before I just can't figure out why it is not working. `asyncFetchContent()` is fired from elsewhere. `contentController` is created elsewhere.

```
function ContentController() {

}

ContentController.prototype.asyncFetchContent = function(){ 

         $.getJSON( '/content/TestContent.json', 
            function(data){
                contentController.displayContentCallback( data ); 
                } 
         );
}

ContentController.prototype.displayContentCallback = function( javascriptObject ){ 
    alert( "in callback");
    $( "#testID" ).html( javascriptObject.title );
}
```

Firebug will accept a breakpoint at the definition of `displayContentCallback()` and stop but then silently fails once you stepover. `javascriptObject` is `undefined`.

Thanks-in-advance,

Guido

Comment: Me thinks it will work if you just use longer names for those functions ?

Comment: Are you sure you should be prototyping. From the way you call the other functions, and the fact that your starting object is empty, maybe an object literal would serve your needs better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error,
>   the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of
>   JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with
>   syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object
>   literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON,
>   whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in
>   double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

Does your JSON contain an error?

Comment: Holy S**t. Thanks. I had a comment in the file which was the problem. Can I have the 3 hours spent working on this back please?

Answer (score 0):

contentController.displayContentCallback( data ); does not exist. a) It's ContentController, not contentController and b) since you're using prototype, it has to be something like

```
function ContentController() {

}

ContentController.prototype.asyncFetchContent = function(){ 

     $.getJSON( '/content/TestContent.json', 
        function(data){
            var x = new ContentController();
            x.displayContentCallback( data ); 
        } 
     );
}

ContentController.prototype.displayContentCallback = function( javascriptObject ){ 
    alert( "in callback");
    $( "#testID" ).html( javascriptObject.title );
}
```

I'm pretty sure that should work.

Comment: Presumably, `contentController` is a variable in their code that contains an instance of `ContentController`.  This is why it's bad to use names that only differ in case as it invites this confusion.

Comment: perhaps, but just in case... it would be nice if they could clear that up though